# Geopoints: From Single Coordinate to Bounds on map

Tags: postgresql, postgis, polygon, geojson, nominatim

I try to figure out how to come from a single given coordinate (lat/lon) to the nearest bounds which enclose this coordinate on a map e.g. streets or sea. 
Here two examples to give you a better understanding of what I mean:

[image]

[image]

What i tried already or thought about:

1. Setting up a Nominatim server and search for the given coordinate via the reverse-function to get the bbox and/or the geojson polygon of this coordinate. -> this only works when the given coordinate is within a POI or for example directly on a street.
2. Writing an algorithm to walk in all 4 or 8 directions (n/e/s/w) and 'stop' when the map layer/surface changes (change = stop for this direction and mark a bounding-point)
3. Building up an image-recognition system using TensorFlow to detect the different colors and 'draw' the polygon. Worked with TensorFlow a couple of times but this seems to be the most tricky solution to implement (but at my current understanding the most precise one)

Does someone of you have any other ideas to get a solution for this problem? Would appreciate any kind of approaches

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you might wanna first select all polygons in which the given point is inside of using [`ST_Contains`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html), and then compute the distance to this point using [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html). If you `ORDER BY` distance and `LIMIT` to `1` result you'll get the nearest polygon, e.g.

Data Sample

```
CREATE TABLE t (gid int, geom geometry);
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
(1,'POLYGON((-4.47 54.26,-4.44 54.28,-4.41 54.24,-4.46 54.23,-4.47 54.26))'),
(2,'POLYGON((-4.48 54.25,-4.40 54.25,-4.41 54.23,-4.48 54.23,-4.48 54.25))'),
(3,'POLYGON((-4.53 54.23,-4.44 54.29,-4.38 54.22,-4.53 54.23))');
```

[image]

Query

```
SELECT gid,ST_AsText(geom) FROM t
WHERE ST_Contains(geom,ST_MakePoint(-4.45, 54.25))
ORDER BY ST_Distance(geom,ST_MakePoint(-4.45, 54.25))
LIMIT 1;

 gid |                               st_astext                                
-----+------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | POLYGON((-4.47 54.26,-4.44 54.28,-4.41 54.24,-4.46 54.23,-4.47 54.26))
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! This makes definetely sense to me but where to get the roads/ways of the whole world as geojson linestrings/polygons?

Comment: ahhh from your question I understood you already had the geometries in your database :D In that case, stick to OpenStreetMaps to get the roads. For administrative borders I definitely recommend gadm.org. Why you need the geometries as geojson? The easiest way to import large amounts of geometries into postgres is imho using shape files. Once you've got them into the db, you can export them in any format you want: gml, geojson, kml, wkt, etc..